# How to change configspec of a dynamic view in clearcase for a specific track

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am new to IBM ClearCase.
I have a dynamic view with named "`current_view`". I am able to set it to the default config spec with the below command.

```
cleartool setcs -tag current_view -default .
```

But now I am trying to set it into specific track.

So how should I give the argument in place of "`-default`", so that config spec will get changed from default to specific configspec?

And one more info I want to know , when I am setting config spec to any specific track from which location and which file "setcs" command is reading 
the track information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is simply to edit the config spec with [`cleartool edcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm):

```
 cd /view/myView
 # or
 cd M:\myView

 cleartool edcs
```

Edit the config spec, and add your branch you want to follow

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../yourBranch/LATEST  <=== Add this line
element * /main/LATEST
```

Save and close: the dynamic view content will automatically adjust to your new selection rules.

---

You could also edit your condif spec in a file, and use that file as an argument of [`cleartool setcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm)

```
 cd /view/myView
 # or
 cd M:\myView

 cleartool setcs afile
```

That way, you can script the all process (no interactive step)

Comment: Hi VonC ,Thanks for your quick suggestion . Actually I am trying to do the same thing through shell script ."edcs" command will force me to do the changes manually .So , it will be better if I can directly pass an argument of track  with setcs command .

Comment: @Abinash yes, that is what my edit shows: in your script, create and appends lines of your config spec you want: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-append-multiple-lines-to-a-file. And then still in your script, call setcs with the file of that file.